# How to make some things not wrap in responsive form?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive form, where some things wrap, and others do not.

I would like the form to look like this on desktop

[image]

and like this on mobile

[image]

Notice that the icon stays to the right. Unfortunately I cannot use a background image for the icon, as I need to show a tooltip on hover of the icon.

When I attempt this, however, the icon wraps:

[image]

So, how can I make the icon be its own element (span or div), yet not wrap below the text field?

Here is one attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/XVu6V/

And here is a Bootstrap 3 attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/syhLJ/1/ I'd really like to use Bootstrap.

Here's some HTML:

```
<div text-element class="form-group row">
    <label for="firstName" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 validation-icon required"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 validation-message">
        Needed for communication.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use a background image and still show a tooltip. Just set it on the div instead of <img> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack **col-xx-xx** together without overriding bootstrap's default styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/99SFW/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div text-element class="form-group row">
            <label for="firstName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 validation-icon required"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 validation-message">Needed for communication.</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!!! That seems to work well. And after adding tooltips, they show up in the correct position, too. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

Why not wrap the icon and `<input>` inside a div, set that div to `position:relative` and add a `padding-right` the same width of the icon. Then set the `<input>` 100% wide and the icon `position:absolute;top:0;right:0`? That'll force the icon to always sit to the right of the `<input>`.

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/syhLJ/7/.

You can view just the HTML preview of it at http://fiddle.jshell.net/syhLJ/7/show/, I use this solution quite a bit and it's never failed so far.

Comment: Since I didn't want to use bootstrap, your answer did the trick in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really optimal but you could try absolutely positioning the input and floating it to the left when on a smaller screen, while floating the icon to the right. Then I guess make the input a percentage that will give you some spacing between it and the icon.

```
.form-group .form-control {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/syhLJ/6/)

The HTML goes something like this...

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon">R</div>
        <div class="validation">Needed for communication.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the css

```
.input {
    float: left;
    width:calc(100% - 35px);
    max-width: 500px;
}
.icon {
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 4px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.validation {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could float the button right and drag it up with a negative margin.

```
.form-group .validation-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -33px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .form-group .validation-icon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;    
  }
}
.form-control {
    width: 90%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Anp7s/2/